# Compiling Code For .Net 2.0 - What Happens If Client Does Not Have This Installed - Will It Default?

Tags: c#, build

If I compile a code and target the C# 2.0 platform and the client only has .NET 3.5 will this application load and run?

EDIT: I know that .NET is backwards compatible - But my question still remains.  If I build this and target framework .net 2.0 but the client has only .NET 4, will the CLR load this and run this with the .NET 4 CLR?

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 **IS** .NET 2.0 - with additional libraries included. So you should be fine here.

Comment: Ok then assume I had .Net 4 only - Would it still load? - My point is do you target a specific version or is this like Java where any version over and above would suffice?

Comment: 2.0 -> 3.5 is a special case. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx for more general info. If you are compiling for 2.0 but have tested that your program works for 4.0 then you ship your program with a configuration file that says it works for both. When Framework 5.0 comes out, then if your program still runs correctly you can get your new users to update the configuration file which can be done using notepad or download a new configuration file and so they don't need the whole application again.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not fault. Version 2.0 is included in version 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

There are some quirks with thos versioning scheme.
Basically there are three CLR runtimes:
CLR 1 (shipped with .Net 1-1.1).
CLR 2 (shipped with .Net 2.0-3.5).
CLR 4 (shipped with .Net 4).
All that is between those number are only incremental changes to the libraries.
So in your example .Net 3.5 is just the same .Net 2.0, but that have more libraries included. Generally this is not a problem, because you can package your project in a way, that it will include any libraries except for .Net 2.0. And it will work on any .Net 2.0 installation.
[Microsoft claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)

That .Net is fully backward compatible. I.e. you can even run .Net 1.1 apps on .Net 4.0. But they say, there may be some problems.
In your case it should be fine, but you have to perform particular tests before you claim this to work.